# Moongoose aggregate $match does not match id's

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to show products by ids (`56e641d4864e5b780bb992c6` and `56e65504a323ee0812e511f2`) and show price after subtracted by discount if available.

I can count the final price using aggregate, but this return all document in a collection, how to make it return only the matches ids

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56e641d4864e5b780bb992c6"), 
"title" : "Keyboard", 
"discount" : NumberInt(10),
"price" : NumberInt(1000)

"_id" : ObjectId("56e65504a323ee0812e511f2"), 
"title" : "Mouse", 
"discount" : NumberInt(0),
"price" : NumberInt(1000)

"_id" : ObjectId("56d90714a48d2eb40cc601a5"), 
"title" : "Speaker", 
"discount" : NumberInt(10),
"price" : NumberInt(1000)
```

this is my query

```
productModel.aggregate([
        {
            $project: {
                title   : 1,
                price: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {$gt: ["$discount", 0]}, then: {$subtract: ["$price", {$divide: [{$multiply: ["$price", "$discount"]}, 100]}]}, else: "$price"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    ], function(err, docs){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(docs)
        }
    })
```

and if i add this `$in` query, it returns empty array

```
productModel.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {_id: {$in: ids}}
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    title   : 1,
                    price: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {$gt: ["$discount", 0]}, then: {$subtract: ["$price", {$divide: [{$multiply: ["$price", "$discount"]}, 100]}]}, else: "$price"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    ], function(err, docs){
        if (err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            console.log(docs)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Your `ids` variable will be constructed of "strings", and not `ObjectId` values.

Mongoose "autocasts" string values for `ObjectId` into their correct type in regular queries, but this [does not happen in the aggregation pipeline](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399), as in described in issue #1399.

Instead you must do the correct casting to type manually:

```js
ids = ids.map(function(el) { return mongoose.Types.ObjectId(el) })
```

Then you can use them in your pipeline stage:

```js
{ "$match": { "_id": { "$in": ids } } }
```

The reason is because aggregation pipelines "typically" alter the document structure, and therefore mongoose makes no presumption that the "schema" applies to the document in any given pipeline stage.

It is arguable that the "first" pipeline stage when it is a `$match` stage should do this, since indeed the document is not altered. But right now this is not how it happens.

Any values that may possibly be "strings" or at least not the correct BSON type need to be manually cast in order to match.

Comment: That's it, it now works. but usually i throw the id as string in findOneAndUpdate or other query, and it works fine, is the problem only happen in aggregate?

Comment: @MuhammadFasalirRahman This is exactly what I answered with. A `.find()` can use the `Schema` which of course has a default type of `ObjectId` for the `_id` field. Aggregation pipelines do **not** use the `Schema`, as I actually already explained.

Comment: took me three days to get here; sigh.. I created a lamda inside my schema static method `const castUserId = (userId) => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)` now i'm happy

Comment: lol....hours wasted on this issue....Thanks for the solution

Comment: Nice work around, but any chance `$in` could be slower than exact match?

Answer (score 19):

1. In the mongoose , it work fine with find({_id:'606c1ceb362b366a841171dc'})
2. But while using the aggregate function we have to use the mongoose object to convert the _id as object eg.

$match: { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("606c1ceb362b366a841171dc") }

This will work fine.

Comment: Awesome! Seems better than using `$in`!

Answer (score 10):

You can simply convert your id to

```
 let id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.query.id);
```

and then match

```
 { $match: { _id: id } },
```

Answer (score 4):

instead of:

```
$match: { _id: "6230415bf48824667a417d56" }
```

use:

```
$match: { _id: ObjectId("6230415bf48824667a417d56") }
```

Comment: Hi Jafar, including where ObjectId comes from would make it easier to follow ;) Upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

Using mongoose 8+ and typescript, I use

```
let newId = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId(id);
```

and then the match stage looks like this

```
"$match" : {
    "_id" : newId
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I am using too but getting "The signature '(inputId: number): ObjectId' of 'mongoose.mongo.ObjectId' is deprecated." this over ObjectId. I m not sure this is give me lots of problem next times.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$match: { $in : [ {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("56e641d4864e5b780bb992c6 ")}, {_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("56e65504a323ee0812e511f2")}] }
```

Because Mongoose autocasts string values for ObjectId into their correct type in regular queries, but this does not happen in the aggregation pipeline. So we need to define ObjectId cast in pipeline queries.