# Whats the better way to reference a mongoose schema objectId

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assuming that i have the following models:

```
var author = mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
isEnabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
}
})

var book = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
value: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
}
authorId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'author'
required: true
},
isEnabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
}
})
```

When I try to make a similar aggregate as demonstrated below:

```
books.aggregate([{$match: { authorId: '599b3b54b8ffff5d1cd323d8'}, { $group: {_id: '$name', total: {$sum: '$value'} } } }])
```

I did not get any registry due to the fact that mongoose does not transform the authorId into ObjectId, I was able to make it work by turning it into ObjectId before inserting it into the filter, but it did not seem like a good implementation, since I had to give a require in mongoose.

I implemented it differently, changed authorId for String, did it worked very well, my question is if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193289/moongoose-aggregate-match-does-not-match-ids and more on https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mongo4.0 and above you can use [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/) to change the data type, or simply `$toObjectId`

find with string objectId to lookup ObjectId

```
db.t10.find({$expr : {$eq : ["$_id" , {$convert : {input : "5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006", to : "objectId"}}]}})
```

aggregate

```
db.t10.aggregate([
    {$match : {$expr : {$eq : ["$_id" , {$convert : {input : "5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006", to : "objectId"}}]}}}
])
```

sample collection

```
> db.t10.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006") }
```

aggregate output

```
> db.t10.aggregate([{$match : {$expr : {$eq : ["$_id" , {$convert : {input : "5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006", to : "objectId"}}]}}}])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006") }
```

find output

```
> db.t10.find({$expr : {$eq : ["$_id" , {$convert : {input : "5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006", to : "objectId"}}]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c269af53f6a8103d9cda006") }
>
```

Comment: This solution is very good, although in my case I had to keep as String, because this option is not available in the database, as you yourself specified, as soon as possible I will update the database and implement this solution, thank you very much for your answer.