# Find a document by Id and filter a subarray in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregate

everyone! I'm looking for a solution to my problems around the internet a few days and after a lot of failed tries, I decided to ask my first question here.

So, I have a model like this:

```js
const Exercise = new Schema (
    {
        description: String,
        duration: Number,
        date: Date
    },
    {
        _id: false
    }
);

const User = new Schema({
    username: String,
    log: [
        Exercise
    ]
});
```

And I would like to find an specific user and filter his/her exercise log in a date range. If there isn't any exercise in the range, I'd just like to return the id, username and the log as an empty array. So, I've built this query:

```js
User.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                _id: userIdInput
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                username: 1,
                log: { 
                    $filter: { 
                        input: "$log", 
                        as: "log", 
                        cond: { 
                            $gte: [ "$$log.date", from ]
                        } 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }])
        .exec()
        .then((log) => {
            res.json(log);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(err);
        });
       
}
```

But this query always return an empty array. Is there anything wrong I'm doing or any tips to compose this query in a better way?

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What's your `from` data type? Is a string, date, number? It should be `Date` to compare values. I've tried [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d6wKydvANRd) and it seems to work ok. It is your query but using `ISODate("...")` instead of `from`.

Comment: @J.F. Hey, I tried the link you sent and it really works. The `from` data type is Date and I'm using `toISOString()` on it. Anyways, it still won't work even if I compare `duration` for exemple. I'm begging to think that the problem is not the query, but it may not be compatible with Mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem is that when we use `aggregate()` in mongoose, we must cast manually the id string to ObjectId type, since it doesn't do it automatically as in `find()` for example.

The resource: [Moongoose aggregate $match does not match id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193289/moongoose-aggregate-match-does-not-match-ids)