# Retrieve all the children of a document from materialized path

Tags: mongodb

I have the following collection that simulates a folder structure using Mongo materialized paths (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/).

[**Mongo playground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3MTFQoCPrsE)

I'm trying that for each id in the `$in` clause, to get all the children and also document defined by the id.

So for example if the input is id `fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f` (which is document with name f3) then the result should be all the children (the entire hierarchy) of f3 + f3.

Collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "f79590d8-20d2-42a4-9f3f-17c2aa30fe19",
    "name": "f1",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "97e94a4e-53e1-44f2-a766-6ca88898fa38",
    "name": "f11",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",f79590d8-20d2-42a4-9f3f-17c2aa30fe19,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "b4eb3f93-a9cf-4fc8-bfa5-ee20a5be9769",
    "name": "f111",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",f79590d8-20d2-42a4-9f3f-17c2aa30fe19,97e94a4e-53e1-44f2-a766-6ca88898fa38,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "82ae9741-c44a-4b06-8526-0debb4a54006",
    "name": "f12",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",f79590d8-20d2-42a4-9f3f-17c2aa30fe19,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "51972fc1-cfff-4179-88a1-29adb1658f52",
    "name": "f2",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "d930ad8c-bde7-49bc-a31c-e63255f02ddc",
    "name": "f21",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",51972fc1-cfff-4179-88a1-29adb1658f52,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f",
    "name": "f3",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ""
  },
  {
    "_id": "3a6ad34a-8cab-4f7b-ad4c-0ed1367fd97e",
    "name": "f31",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "e05fc977-7b98-40e9-ac72-a296f45872c8",
    "name": "f32",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "107218eb-df68-46de-b176-d70d1202f373",
    "name": "f33",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "88464a81-250f-4318-a8c8-349809e348df",
    "name": "f331",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,107218eb-df68-46de-b176-d70d1202f373,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "799181dd-38bd-4142-a2f6-015a4eb8e160",
    "name": "f3311",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,107218eb-df68-46de-b176-d70d1202f373,88464a81-250f-4318-a8c8-349809e348df,"
  },
  {
    "_id": "b84b918d-ac92-4ab0-8d78-8d954100afad",
    "name": "f332",
    "createdBy": "lubix",
    "application": "mihoho",
    "path": ",fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,107218eb-df68-46de-b176-d70d1202f373,"
  }
]
```

My attempt for a query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "_id": {
        $in: [
          "fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f",
          "97e94a4e-53e1-44f2-a766-6ca88898fa38"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "panda": {
        "$cond": [
          {
            "$eq": [
              "$path",
              ""
            ]
          },
          {
            "$concat": [
              ",",
              "$_id",
              ","
            ]
          },
          {
            "$concat": [
              "$path",
              "$_id",
              ","
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "rgx": {
        $concat: [
          "^",
          "$panda"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // {'$match': {'path':{$regex: '^,fc56c12b-181a-49e3-85a2-4474552bea6f,'}}}
  // {$addFields: {'dodo':{ $regexFind: {input: '$path', regex:'$rgx'}}}}
  ])
```

Comment: This explains it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193289/moongoose-aggregate-match-does-not-match-ids

TLDR the aggregate pipeline does not use ObjectID but instead treats them as strings

Comment: @Kelsey which is good. As data type the id field is String in database. Or am I missing something?